# How can I implement an interface type using a explicit class

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IReplaceable
{
    int ParentID { get; set; }

    IReplaceable Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface IApproveable
{
    bool IsAwaitingApproval { get; set; }

    IApproveable Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to implement it in the class like so:

```
public class Agency :  IReplaceable, IApproveable
{
     public int AgencyID { get; set; }
     // other properties

     private int ParentID { get; set; }

     // implmentation of the IReplaceable and IApproveable property
     public Agency Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't implement an interface with a method (or property) that doesn't satisfy the interface's signature. Consider this:

```
IReplaceable repl = new Agency();
repl.Parent = new OtherReplaceable(); // OtherReplaceable does not inherit Agency
```

How should the type checker evaluate this? It would be valid by the signature of `IReplaceable`, but not by the signature of `Agency`.

Instead, consider using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) like this:

```
public class Agency : IReplaceable
{
    public int AgencyID { get; set; }
    // other properties

    private int ParentID { get; set; }

    public Agency Parent { get; set; }

    IReplaceable IReplaceable.Parent
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.Parent;          // calls Agency Parent
        }
        set
        {
            this.Parent = (Agency)value; // calls Agency Parent
        }
    }

    IApproveable IApproveable.Parent
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.Parent;          // calls Agency Parent
        }
        set
        {
            this.Parent = (Agency)value; // calls Agency Parent
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when you do something like this:

```
IReplaceable repl = new Agency();
repl.Parent = new OtherReplaceable();
```

The type checker considers this valid by the signature of the `IReplaceable`, so it compiles just fine, but it would throw an [`InvalidCastException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx) at run time (of course, you can implement your own logic if you don't want an exception). However, if you do something like this:

```
Agency repl = new Agency();
repl.Parent = new OtherReplaceable();
```

It will not compile, because the type checker will know that `repl.Parent` must be an `Agency`.

Comment: Darn, you got there before me - explicit interface implementation is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can [implement it explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). That's why they exist.

```
public class Agency : IReplaceable, IApproveable
{
    public int AgencyID { get; set; }

    int IReplaceable.ParentID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    bool IApproveable.IsAwaitingApproval
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    IApproveable IApproveable.Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    IReplaceable IReplaceable.Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Sadly you can't access it via class instance, you need to cast it to interface in order to use them.

```
Agency agency = ...;
agency.Parent = someIApproveable;//Error
agency.Parent = someIReplaceable;//Error
((IApproveable)agency).Parent = someIApproveable;//Works fine
((IReplaceable)agency).Parent = someIReplaceable;//Works fine
```